# WCF 4 Service with REST/SOAP endpoints in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

Hello and thank you for reading.

I'm trying to get a service hosted in IIS 7.5, that has multiple endpoints exposed.

I have a feeling the problem lies within my web.config, but I'll post my service code in here. There's no interface file, as I'm using the newer features of WCF 4, there's also no .svc file.

All the routing, from my understanding is handled in Global.asax.cs using the RouteTable feature.

Regardless, onto the code / config -

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
// NOTE: If the service is renamed, remember to update the global.asax.cs file
public class Service1
{
    // TODO: Implement the collection resource that will contain the SampleItem instances

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And now, the config with the changes I thought would need to be made (I'm not sure if I needed to keep the standardEndpoints block, but with or without it I'm still getting error messages. -

```
<services>
  <service name="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="HttpGetMetadata">
    <endpoint name="rest"
              address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1"
              behaviorConfiguration="REST" />
    <endpoint name="soap"
              address="soap"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1" />
    <endpoint name="mex"
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>    

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpGetMetadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

The Global.asax.cs file was left alone.

Again I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my config. The error I'm getting when I try to access any of the endpoints defined is -

> The endpoint at '' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Thanks,

Zachary Carter

Comment: What URL do you use to access your service??

Comment: Also: you say you don't have an *.svc file - how is your service activated then? Either you need a *.svc file, or you need a <serviceActivations> tag in your <serviceHostingEnvironment> config.

Comment: The service is deployed to the default website on port 80 so it's just - http://localhost/WebApp/ServiceName to access it. Also, the ability to create services without a .svc file is a new feature in .NET 4.0. Instead of hitting the svc file a new class has been added to correctly route the request to the appropriate service.

Comment: Can you **show us** how you have added the service to the route table?? That would most likely be in `global.asax.cs` - which you said you didn't touch - so that makes me wonder......

Comment: Sure - private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
        }

Comment: Marc I'm thinking it has to do with the conflicting binding configurations set on the service / endpoint. The one on the service enables webhttp and the one on the endpoint neables basichttpbinding which conflict. Also just in case you were curious - here's a good blog post about WCF in .NET 4 - http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/drop-the-soap-wcf-rest-and-pretty-uris-in-net-4

Comment: Can you please **update** your original post with the code - it's just **really hard to read** here in comments....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I tried to replicate your stuff - works like a charm for me :-)

- I used your service class - no changes
- I used your `RegisterRoutes` call in `global.asax.cs`

When I launch the web app from within Visual Studio, I get Cassini (the built-in web server) come up on `http://localhost:3131/` - this might wary in your case.

Now, I can easily navigate there with a second browser window, and I do get a simple response on this URL:

```
http://localhost:3131/Service1/HelloWorld
+--------------------+ 
 from Cassini
                     +--------+
                   name (first param) in ServiceRoute registration
                              +-----------+
                               from your URI template on the WebGet attribute
```

Does the same URL work for you??

**Update:** here's my config - I can connect to `http://localhost:3131/Service1/HelloWorld` in the browser using REST, and I can connect to `http://localhost:3131/Service1/soap` with the WCF Test Client to make a SOAP call (my `Service1` lives in the `RestWebApp` namespace - thus my service and contract names are a tad different than yours - but other than that, I believe it's identical to your own config):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment     
        aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="RestWebApp.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Meta">
        <endpoint name="rest" 
                  address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="RestWebApp.Service1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="REST" />
        <endpoint name="SOAP"
            address="soap"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="RestWebApp.Service1" />
        <endpoint name="mex"
            address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Meta">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Marc, it definitely does if I leave the config file alone. My issue is as soon as I try to expose an additional endpoint configured to use basicHttpBinding, the original REST endpoint craps out and the newly exposed endpoint fails to be found as well.

Comment: My soap endpoint looks like - <endpoint name="soap"
                  address="soap"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1" />

But navigating to http://localhost:80/Service1/soap produces the following error message - 

The endpoint at 'http://vm-scctest.amcad.com/AiSynthDocSvc/Service1/soap' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Comment: Again I think this has to do with the service having a behavior configuration set to webHttpBinding and the endpoint behavior configuration set to use basicHttpBinding.

Comment: @Zachary Carter: I don't think so - you've given your endpoint behavior (which has `webHttp` in it) a name, so only if you actually define it on the <endpoint> tag, it should be used. Or did you not really post your real config?? Do you have a default endpoint behavior (without a name) lying around that gets applied to **all** endpoints??

Comment: I think I included it. This is I think might be causing the problem - 

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpGetMetadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

<service name="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="HttpGetMetadata">

Comment: And then in my restful end point I use - 

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

<endpoint name="soap"
              address="soap"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="AiSynthDocSvc.Service1" />

Comment: @marc_s do you think you could copy / paste the config you have for your service so I can compare mine to yours?

Comment: @zachary carter: that service behavior you have defined is pretty straightforward and really shouldn't cause any issues like you're seeing...

Comment: @marc_s I'm wondering if it's something wrong with IIS then. Back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: @marc_s I have no idea what it was, but replacing your config with mine solved the issue. Thanks a ton for your help marc_s you've been invaluably helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this it helped me a lot.

The issue in my case was that I had a default behaviour configured that contains webHttp. After giving it the name="REST" and setting my webHttpBinding endpoint behaviourConfiguration ="REST" I had no further errors.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IMobileService">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6862/silverlight/services/MobileService.svc"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IMobileService"
    contract="AlchemyMobileService.IMobileService" name="CustomBinding_IMobileService" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="MobileService.Alchemy">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/mobileservice" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MobileService.IAlchemy" behaviorConfiguration="REST">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```